# Using URLFOR() to refer to the current page dynamically

Tags: visualforce, urlfor

I need to add a link to a VF page which opens the current page with an additional parameter (to allow an embedded VF page to redirect to itself as a non-embedded page).  I have this, which works:

```
<apex:commandLink action="{!URLFOR('/apex/ListPage', id, [id=id, fullpage='1'])}" 
                   value="Full List" />
```

This works fine, but I don't want the hardcoded page name.  I've tried `$CurrentPage` ("Incorrect Argument type for function URLFOR"), `$CurrentPage.url` ("Invalid target parameter for function URLFOR), and even `$CurrentPage.geturl` ("Field getUrl does not exist", which proves that `$CurrentPage.url` refers to something).  `$CurrentPage.name` compiles (I can save the page) but clicking the resulting link gives the error, "Formula Expression is required on the action attributes."

The other option that works is `$Apex.ListPage`, but while it's not a string, it's still specific to the page name; I'd prefer something that would work in any page without edits.  Possible?

**aside**: I'm passing the id as second param, but it was being ignored, so I added it to the extra param array, and it works fine.  Not sure why that's needed, but it's working.

Comment: Why commandLink and not outputLink? Looks like you just want to start fresh, with new params passed via url. So regular link without `commandLink / commandButton` "side effects" should be OK and more forgiving ;). Another option might be to use embedded `<apex:param>`s (don't make the link a self-closing tag)

Comment: Can you use `{!URLFOR('/apex/' + $CurrentPage.Name, ...)}`?

Comment: @user320 yep, prefixing `'/apex/'` did the trick.  Accepted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something like this what you're looking for?

```
{!URLFOR('/apex/' + $CurrentPage.Name, null, ['id'=id])}
```

It will compile into URLFOR alright, and resolve to an absolute URL including namespace:

```
https://namespace.na14.visual.force.com/apex/Relative?id=000000000000000AAA
```

> I'm passing the id as second param, but it was being ignored, so I added it to the extra param array, and it works fine. Not sure why that's needed, but it's working.

I think that second parameter is strictly for `$Action` URLs. Otherwise it's dropped.

Comment: Ah further mysteries of the URLFOR function explained! :-)

Comment: Seems silly that `$Page.PageName` works, but `$CurrentPage` doesn't.  Mysteries indeed!

Comment: re: StandardController - The page in question uses a standard controller and a controller extension.

Comment: Derp >.< fixed - my bad @JasonClark

Comment: For other URLFOR mysteries, I find myself referring to this page all the time:  http://salesforcesource.blogspot.com/2008/12/urlfor-function-finally-explained.html

Comment: You'll need to append namespace c__ to all parameters. "c__id"